# Virus Definitions Database Download Link For Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Tags: anti-virus, updates, sep

Where can I download the virus definitions database file for Symantec Endpoint Protection, so that I can perform an offline import-and-update?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking for the link to download the definitions for Symantec Endpoint Protection manually?

Comment: sry... let me explain... our office use end point but the one place of office can't access internet connection... so i would like to download offline virus definition update for Symantec Endpoint... and use for without internet connection area.

Answer (score 1):

If you require the definition updates for Symantec Endpoint Protection, they can be found here.  [SEP Def Download Page](http://www.symantec.com/business/security_response/definitions/download/detail.jsp?gid=savce)

Comment: no... it's not Def download page... it's just client installer program...

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand. The link is to the definitions. 20110802-024-v5i32.exe is the latest def file for Symantec Endpoint 11and a number of other versions.  Are you saying you need the client itself?

Comment: i already download with your link... i run this file in computer... but virus update is still 2009 date.